# Shortest distance matrix given an adjacency matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

If I have an adjacency matrix, how can I find a matrix that has the shortest distance between each pair of nodes? (distance matrix, but the nodes are not in a euclidean space)

I'm trying to implement a [Self Organising Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map) with an arbitrary topology, given by the adjacency matrix, so I want to be able to use the vectors of the the distance matrix to determine how far to move the other nodes in the SOM.

Comment: pretty good suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079876/converting-a-adjacency-matrix-to-a-distance-or-hop-matrix I suggest you read that and ask a question there if you are still unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @WillJagy. That leads to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths, which is a great kick-off point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to look at using the Floyd-Warshall Algorithm to solve the all-pairs shortest paths problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm